# Android fragment transaction error when "clean up memory"

Tags: android, android-fragments

**Short story:**

I got error when use FragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(....).
When I checking animation listener is only call onStartAnimation & not call onEndAnimation. (it's only happen when I use some tool optimized ram).

**Long story:**

Here is follow I test in my app.

Input:
We have 2 fragment A, B. MainActivity will open fragment A then open Fragment B. When user press back -> back to fragment A.

Step:

1. Open fragment A.
2. Open fragment B.
3. Use some tool like battery doctor -> Optimized Ram.
4. Open app -> Current still in Fragment B.
5. Press back to go to fragment A.

=> Animation never call onAnimationEnd && APP STUCK. I can do anything in with my app.

Notes: If I don't use some tool for "Optimized Ram" -> It always working as well.

Please help me for fix this bug !

**UPDATE**
I just got Log when app "lag".

```
Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21$1', referenced from method android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.setEpicenter
```

Comment: The log message you get is a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77670) in support library on old android platforms. What happens on android 5.0.2 ?

Comment: But what do you think about it only happen when I use "optimized ram" ?

Comment: Looks like VM is garbage collecting something weakly referenced. Also, this specific bug was introduced in v21 version of library. Try using `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'` version.

Comment: @S.D. I create new BaseFragment && override method: onCreateAnimation. Then I add this code:
 try {
            anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), nextAnim);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error when load animation: " + e.getMessage());
            // Ignore.
        }
=> When it crash whole app (Message is "app not response") I get log:
Error when load animation: Resource ID #0x0

(Resource id is #0x0 because I try use NO ANIMATION.)

Comment: @S.D. When I setting target version to 19 => I don't see crash :| (What's do you think about it ? I still use support-v4:21+)

Comment: API 19+ seems not to depend on support stuff, but its own classes.